# Filter to hide/show images in browser based on image description text

Tags: html, image

I am very interested in improving my browsing experience by never seeing images of the cast of "Friends" again.  I know that I can uncheck "show pictures" in IE's advanced options, but I would prefer to just filter out certain images based on the description text.  Is it possible in any browser to show most images, but hide an image if the description contains "Aniston" for example?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't know the "description"/tag of the image of a website before you are on it and inspecting it. So to my knowledge it's not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an Extension to do this, or add a bookmark with an Url of:

```
javascript:(document.querySelectorAll("img[alt=Aniston]").forEach(img=>img.style.display="none"))
```

to your Bookmarks. Everytime you click on that bookmark, all image elements with an Describtion of "Aniston" will be hidden.
If you want an Extension to do this, contact me.